# How to make a Flutter app listen to incoming calls using WebRTC and Web Socket for signalling

Tags: flutter, webrtc

been looking for the answer over a few days but no luck so I think I better ask SO. Here is my scenario: I'm trying to create a Flutter WebRTC video call app which is similar to WhatsApp or Viber. I use a simple web socket to do signalling so that I can display caller name when there is an incoming call from the other end and depends on callee's action like Accept and Reject the call they can either engage or just simply hang up the call. All working well so far. The problem however I'm facing is when either parties not using the app, the other party can't make a call because they can't send the signal. I think when the app is not running its not connecting to the web socket. How can I make the app keep listening efficiently to call signal events even its not running? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need something that notifies the application that there's some incoming call/data even when the application is not running.

I'll recommend to use Firebase Notification Service. Although you can also use Pushy or Pusher Beam for this task.

Upon receiving the notification, you can perform desired task based on the data payload received through the notification.

Comment: Thanks @Jaswant. I'll check it out.